# Update date field to the same date one month back Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date field in Oracle I need to Update the date Field so that it is on the same date one month back without changing the day date. For example:

```
10-09-2013 should be 10-08-2013
13-05-2013 should be 13-04-2013
02-02-2013 should be 02-01-2013
```

I had thought of

```
update my_table_name set my_date_field = my_date_field-30
```

but not all the months have 30 days. Please help me out

Comment: use add_months(date,-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE My_table_name
SET my_date_field = ADD_MONTHS( my_date_field, -1)
```

Comment: Be carefull: 2013-02-28 will be 2013-01-31